# Problems with select AngularJs

Tags: angularjs

I have a few problems.

There are 2 objects in my scope:
1)

```
tasks:
    12:
        id: 12
        user_id: 1
```

2)

```
users:
    1:
        id: 1
        username:  sergey
```

I'm trying to render select with default value (in this example it must be sergey):

```
<select class="form-control"
    data-ng-model="tasks[task.id].user_id"
    data-ng-change="setWorker(task.id)"
>
    <option data-ng-repeat="user in users" data-ng-value="user.id" data-ng-selected="{[{user.id == task.user_id}]}">{[{user.username}]}</option>
</select>
```

But it finished with 2 errors (my problems):
1) In my select default value is empty option
2) In my select there is an additional option o_O like:

```
<option value="? number:4 ?"></option>
```

First i thought that happened, because server response was containing promise. I resolved this with toJSON all my data, for example:

```
$scope.users = data.toJSON();
```

Also i have a third problem:
After updating my data and successful query to my server, for example trying to change user_id in task, i want to update my scope and i do it like:

```
$scope.tasks[taksId].user_id = userId;
```

And after that i want to execute my own function test(), and i'm trying to do this through watcher:

```
$scope.$watch('tasks', function () {
    $scope.test();
 })
```

But nothing happened. Have you any idea? =\

Comment: The `? number:4 ?` part is just an angular internal  thing, telling it that the value (4) is from numeric type, so when you bind it to `ngModel` you'll get `$scope.tasks[task.id].user_id === 4` (number) instead of `$scope.tasks[task.id].user_id === "4"` (string)

Comment: So, how can i escape it? I just want bind to ngModel my task.user_id from tasks by task_id. It looks simple but nothing work. I tried to render this select in different ways, but failed any time(

Comment: I think you can try removing `data-ng-selected="{[{user.id == task.user_id}]}"` and replacing it with `data-ng-init="tasks[task.id].user_id = (user.id == task.user_id) ? user.id : tasks[task.id].user_id"`

Comment: same result, but now my options has value of username like <option value="sergey">...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using an `ng-repeat` try using `ng-options` like this:

```
<select class="form-control"
    data-ng-model="tasks[task.id].user_id"
    data-ng-change="setWorker(task.id)"
    data-ng-options="user.id as user.username for user in users">
</select>
```

Using `ng-options` allows you to have **non-string** value types. Basically this says "for every user in the users collection, create an option with the text from user.username and the value from user.id".

Comment: thanks it works as well as:
`ng-options='v.id as v.username for (k,v) in users'`

So first problem resolved, but i have another one:
After updating my data and successful query to my server i change user_id in $scope.task like:

`$scope.tasks[taksId].user_id = userId;`
And after that i want to execute my own function `test()` and i'm trying to do this through watcher:

`$scope.$watch('tasks', function () {
    $scope.test();
 })`
I read about $watchCollection, tried id but any effect. I must use $scope.test() after every change in $scope.tasks

Comment: Would you mind creating a separate question for that so you can expound on what change you're trying to watch for, what exactly you're expecting to be firing that watcher that isn't and what it is you're trying to accomplish? I think if you do that you will receive a much better response.